# Where can I see details on why a package threw an error in sublime text

Tags: laravel, sublimetext2

I'm using Jeffery Way's sublime text generator for laravel found [here](https://github.com/JeffreyWay/Laravel-4-Generators).

I run the `laravel generate:migration` command from the control pallet.

It asks for the migration name and I enter `create_users_table`.

Then it asks for the fields and I enter `username:string, password:string`

Then when I hit enter it says `Oh snap, generate migrate failed`

Now while I'm sure my error is a simple typo that any of you would be able to point out, what I'm really curious is if there is a way I can view any more details on why it threw the error?

Requested log result from comment below

```
[2013-11-30 04:37:14] log.ERROR: exception 'InvalidArgumentException' with message 'There are no commands defined in the "generate" namespace.' in C:\Sites\learning-laravel\vendor\symfony\console\Symfony\Component\Console\Application.php:523
Stack trace:
#0 C:\Sites\learning-laravel\vendor\symfony\console\Symfony\Component\Console\Application.php(561): Symfony\Component\Console\Application->findNamespace('generate')
#1 C:\Sites\learning-laravel\vendor\symfony\console\Symfony\Component\Console\Application.php(188): Symfony\Component\Console\Application->find('generate:migrat...')
#2 C:\Sites\learning-laravel\vendor\symfony\console\Symfony\Component\Console\Application.php(121): Symfony\Component\Console\Application->doRun(Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Output\ConsoleOutput))
#3 C:\Sites\learning-laravel\artisan(59): Symfony\Component\Console\Application->run()
#4 {main} [] []
```

Comment: Do you have any log files generated in your `app/storage/logs` directory that shed any light?

Comment: That is exactly what I was looking for. And the issue was that while I had the sublime text portion fo the package installed, I didn't do the laravel portion. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Today I encountered the same problem. And I solved the problem as follow:

step1:  Open app/config/app.php, and add a new item in your providers array

```
    'Way\Generators\GeneratorsServiceProvider'
```

step2:  Open your terminal and enter your laravel application execute 
       'composer update'

step3:  In your SublimeText execute 'Laravel Artisan:Clear cache'

step4:  Restart your sublimeText and it's all ok!

wish this can help you!